# DocBlox CodeIgniter No direct script access

Tags: codeigniter, docblox

I've just installed DocBlox on Windows running Apache.

In a CodeIgniter application I have removed the following line from the top of my script

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

But when I run

```
docblox -f main.php -t docs
```

I get the error message

```
No direct script access allowed
```

Does anyone know what else is stopping this from working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Short version**
You probably have a class that is not in the source that DocBlox parses but is in your include_path. Try to find which file causes this error using the verbose (-v) option and check which classes are not in your project's source but are being invoked.

**Explanation**
DocBlox does not load files using Reflection and should thus not execute the given code *unless* a class could not be found in the project files but could be found using the include_path.

For example:

```
class A extends B
{
}
```

if class B is not parsed by DocBlox then DocBlox will try to find it in your include path so that information can be gathered on it. In this case A is not executed but B is.